# Not able to load store in Ember app loaded in Therubyracer

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a simple Ember application for collecting data from a user about gas well volumes. It is a mobile application synchronizing with a server, so I am trying to use CouchDB to handle the data. The client needs the data in a SQL store, so I am trying to map Ember's ORM onto ActiveRecord's by loading the Ember app in Therubyracer.

I can get the frameworks to load without errors, but when I try to access the store to create a new record, it is undefined. The code I am using to access the store is:

```
var store = App.__container__.lookup('store:main')
```

Are there any other possible methods for accessing the Ember store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The store isn't available until dependency injection has finished loading.  The most accessible hook for this is the ready hook on the app.

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  ready:function(){
   console.log(App.__container__.lookup('store:main'));
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/450/edit